# HLSL Compiler error?

Tags: compiler-construction, directx, direct3d, hlsl

```
float4x4 matInvViewProj;

float4 GetPointPosition(float2 Tex0)
{
    float4 PosImageSpace;
    PosImageSpace.xy = float2(Tex0*2-1);
    PosImageSpace.z = tex2D(DepthTextureSampler,Tex0).r;
    return mul(PosImageSpace,matInvViewProj);
}
```

That's a part of my pixelshader. Why is there a compiler error?
I'm compiling it in `ps_3_0.`
Without the `mul()` it compiles.

Comment: What error are you getting? It compiles fine here.

Comment: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator\Desktop\Programme\3d\Litte3DEngine2\bin\Release\Shader\Directional_Lighting_Shader_Default.fx(91): ID3DXEffectCompiler::CompileEffect: There was an error compiling expression
ID3DXEffectCompiler: Compilation failed

Comment: line 91 : PixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 PS();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I guess that makes sense. Since the w componenet is not initialized, the mul() function will fail.

To avoid it you could initialize your vector as follows:

```
float4 PosImageSpace = (float4)0;
```

I will still recommend you to try compiling your shader using fxc in debug mode, as you can get much better error descriptions that way. You can even set up a custom build step that lets you right click the .fx file and compile it without having to compile the entire solution/project.

To compile the shader using fxc in a debug configuration:

```
fxc /Od /Zi /T fx_3_0 /Fo Directional_Lighting_Shader_Defaul.fxo Directional_Lighting_Shader_Defaul.fx
```

You can find fxc in C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK\Utilities\bin

To set up a custom build step in Visual Studio [check this sample from the DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204839%28VS.85%29.aspx) and also [check this site](http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/8205)

Also check [this article on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509710%28VS.85%29.aspx) about using fxc.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird:
I added this line:

```
PosImageSpace.w = 0.0f;
```

and now it compiles well.
That's how it looks now:

```
float4x4 matInvViewProj;

float4 GetPointPosition(float2 Tex0)
{
    float4 PosImageSpace;
    PosImageSpace.xy = float2(Tex0*2-1);
    PosImageSpace.z = tex2D(DepthTextureSampler,Tex0).r;
    PosImageSpace.w = 0.0f;
    return mul(PosImageSpace,matInvViewProj);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a bit more information. It was just easier than writing it all in a comment :)